# Google Charts and ColdFusion PDF

Tags: charts, coldfusion, google-visualization, pdf-generation

I got this working, but in the most convoluted way possible.  I don't want to duplicate this method for other reports if there is a better way.

Because the Google Image Charts are deprecated, which would have been SO much easier, I decided to go with the JavaScript version of Google Charts.  In order to get this to work, I inserted a cfinclude into the main report program that used jQuery/AJAX, to insert the graph into the report.  No problem.  Easy.  Displays great!

BUT, getting the report into PDF output was another story.  Here’s what I did:

1. First, I had to decide which PDF product to use.  I explored many 3rd party PDF products, but ended up with CFHTMLTOPDF.  I tried CFDOCUMENT, but it did not like the PNG output option from Google Charts at all.
2. The other tricky thing was that with the cfinclude method of inserting the chart on the page, the cfhtmltopdf tag was rendering before the chart.  Argh!  No matter what I did, it would not display.  I tested it by pasting in “rendered” html and it worked, so I knew it was possible.
3. So, as one step of the process, I create the html containing the report data and the charts.  jQuery does most of the heavy lifting, looping through the data and drawing the charts.  The html is wrapped in a container, and jQuery grabs the finished html string and submits/posts it to another program.
4. This next program takes the html and writes a .cfm file using the cffile tag.  Now that this “rendered” .cfm page exists, the program calls a final program.  This program uses the cfinclude tag to wrap this “rendered” page in a cfhtmltopdf tag, and TaDa!  Out comes a beautiful report!

Seems ridiculous to go through all of this!  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a ColdFusion tag that would stop the cfhtmltopdf tag from rendering before the cfinclude?  Doesn't JavaScript, being client-side, happen before the cfhtmltopdf tag?

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: (Edit) *"Doesn't JavaScript, being client-side, happen before the cfhtmltopdf tag?"* Client side code always executes **after** server side code. *"tried CFDOCUMENT, but it did not like the PNG output option from Google Charts at all."* Charts submits a base64 image. IIRC, cfdocument doesn't understand those.  You have to decode it into a binary image first. I suspect you omitted that step. But ... as mentioned, it would really help to see a small example of your code. –